# Catch exception of a async method

Tags: c#

Hello I want to catch a Exception of a async method but it did not work look a this example :

```
        public void TryToCatchException()
        {
            try
            {
                _ =LongRunningMethod();
            }
            catch (MyException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("catched");
            }
        }


        public static async Task LongRunningMethod()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Task.Delay(1000); //simulation of work
                    throw new ArgumentException(); // this is a example
                }
                catch (ArgumentException)
                {
                    throw new MyException;
                }

            });
        }
```

if I launch the debugger will say that the exception "MyException" is NOT catched... can someone help me ?

Comment: Why are you using Task.Run?

Comment: @JHBonarius because I use a API Method that block the current thread for 10 to 15 seconds and I don't want that.

Comment: Do not mix `Task` and threads

Comment: As you don't await `LongRunningMethod`, TryToCatchException will return (almost) immediately and cannot catch any exceptions.

Comment: @KlausGütter Thanks you for your response :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you discard tasks, those exceptions are not observed:

```
_ =LongRunningMethod();
```

If you want to catch exceptions from `LongRunningMethod`, then you need to `await` the task returned from that method:

```
await LongRunningMethod();
```

Comment: Thanks you for your comment, but my debugger still say that the exception is "Exception User-Unhandled". ^^ That is normal ?

Comment: Yes, when you run it in the debugger.